# Is there a better way to extract SIC and Fiscal Year End from this web page?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is the link: https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=20&owner=exclude&action=getcompany&Find=Search

I want to extract SIC (i.e. 3823) and year end (i.e. 0102). My code is as follows. It works, but I feel it is cumbersome. What is a better way? Thanks.

```
#soup is a BeatutifulSoup soup object

link_tags = soup.find_all("a")
if link_tags:
    for link in link_tags:

        if "SIC=" in link.get("href"):
            sic = link.string.strip()


re_yend = re.compile(r"Fiscal Year End: *(\d{4})")
match = re_yend.search(str(soup))
if match:
    y_end = str(match.group(1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to get the data from the website:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


def get_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise ValueError('Cannot read the data')
    return response.text


def get_sic_fiscal(data):
    soup = bs(data, 'html.parser')
    # Get the compagny info block
    company_info = soup.find('div', {'class': 'companyInfo'})
    # Get the acronym tag
    acronym = company_info.find('acronym', {'title': 'Standard Industrial Code'})
    # find the next url to acronym tag
    sic = acronym.findNext('a')
    # Reduce the search of the fiscal year end only
    # in the compagny info block
    fiscal_year_end = re.search(r'Fiscal Year End:\s+(\d+)', company_info.text)
    if fiscal_year_end:
        return sic.text, fiscal_year_end.group(1)
    return sic.text, None



url = 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=20&owner=exclude&action=getcompany&Find=Search'

data = get_data(url)
sic, fiscal = get_sic_fiscal(data)

print('SIC: {sic} and Fiscal year end: {fiscal}'.format(sic=sic, fiscal=fiscal))
```

Output:

```
SIC: 3823 and Fiscal year end: 0102
```

Comment: This is thorough!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the search for SIC significantly with a css selector that looks for `SIC` in the href. Your approach to finding the fiscal year is pretty good, although there's no need to explicitly compile the regex and if you know the data will always be there, you could also eliminate the match check:

```
print(soup.select_one('.identInfo a[href*="SIC"]').text)
print(re.search(r"Fiscal Year End: *(\d+)", soup.text).group(1))
```

Result:

```
3823
0102
```

Comment: This is short and sweet!